# Detect click on a specified area

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="main">
hello world
<div id="second-div">
bye
</div>
</div>

jQuery('#main:not(second-div)').click(function() {
alert('works!');
});
```

I want to detect mouse click on the "main" div, but the click event shouldn't trigger when I click on the "second-div" div.
I've tried using ":not(second-div)" but the click triggers anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the target property of the event. *(Edited to reflect the improvement proposal from the comment)*

```
jQuery('#main').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target===this) {
        alert("works!");
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rZeXa/

Comment: **+1** Brilliant Answer since it uses only 1 Click Event listener.

Comment: Plus, you can condense it further using `if(e.target===this)`  for the most minimal code maintaining pure JavaScript too.  :-D

Comment: jQuery('#main').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target===this) {
        alert("works!");
    }
});​ works best - Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try this: http://jsfiddle.net/N6G62/

This should help the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('#main').click(function(e) {

    alert('works!');

});


$('#main div').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});

​
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is weird....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(this).click(function(e){
            if($(e.originalEvent.originalTarget).prop('id')=='main'){  
              alert('You have clicked on Main') 
            }
   })                       
 });
```

Just wanted to share something that i have learned today....

Comment: **+1** Nice to share, learning spreads! Also, I like this THE BEST since it's easy to read quickly and sticks with 1 single Click Event. Thanks and I hope somebody bakes you a cake!

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution like the one provided by Daniel.
I always use `is` to identifiy like this:

```
jQuery('#main').click(function(event) {
  if(!$(event.target).is('#second-div'))
   {
     alert('works');
   }
});
```

Comment: **+1** `.is()` is Fantastic! Using `if($(event.target).is(this))` allows for direct operation of `parent` div while ignoring all `child` div's too.

Comment: @arttronics : very true with `this`

Answer (score -1):

You should call

```
    event.stopPropagation();
```

on the first line of your click handler. this shall stop the propagation of events in the heirarchy.

Comment: **-1** Your answer does not work in OP's [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6G62/1/). I will un-downvote if you edit your answer to work.

Comment: @arttronics, thanks for the favor, the answer was merely a try to help someone, if you wish to depreciate such efforts, you are welcome.